# Can I bring this Side Window Deflector aboard an aircraft in the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, hand-luggage, aircraft

I recently ordered [these window deflectors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0091U4UQ0) for my Mazda:

[image: the deflectors]

But I didn't account for the fact that they are very big, and don't fit in my suitcase (they are 45 x 3.6 x 3 inches in size). I am worried that I won't be let aboard the plane with them since they look kind-of "weapon-ish"...

Is my concern valid? Would it be legal to bring them on a flight from Ohio to New York?

Comment: Question is: what are they made of?

Comment: @JoErNanO it's plastic afaik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't fit in a suitcase, it's highly unlikely the airline will let you bring it on as carry-on, "weapony" or not (although I doubt those fit the bill).

What you can do is check them in as **oversized luggage**, preferably securely packed in bubble wrap or, better yet, the original packaging. Fees may apply depending on your airline, and you'll likely be directed to a separate counter to check in and later pick them up at the destination.

Comment: The problem indeed is not their "weapon"-y appearance whatever that means, this is not our favorite user trying to bring a deactivated bazooka on the plane, rather the size: if it won't fit in your checked luggage for sure you can't carry it on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I will just send it back, not worth the trouble...